# Uncaught TypeError is not a function, but Data is Array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Im sure this is a simple error

```
const orderedByObjectMapFilter = inventors.map((inventor) => {
     var allYearData = inventor.passed
     var newYearData = allYearData.sort((a,b) => a.passed > b.passed? +1 : -1 )
     return newYearData
 
 })
console.log(orderedByObjectMapFilter)
```

this is the data it is coming from:

Simply trying to put the array passed in order after mapping it out. usually get this if it is not an Array. But surely this is an Array?

Also feel free to offer alternatives of code that would be more efficient.

```
const inventors = [
    { first: 'Albert', last: 'Einstein', year: 1879, passed: 1955 },
    { first: 'Isaac', last: 'Newton', year: 1643, passed: 1727 },
    { first: 'Galileo', last: 'Galilei', year: 1564, passed: 1642 },
    { first: 'Marie', last: 'Curie', year: 1867, passed: 1934 },
    { first: 'Johannes', last: 'Kepler', year: 1571, passed: 1630 },
    { first: 'Nicolaus', last: 'Copernicus', year: 1473, passed: 1543 },
    { first: 'Max', last: 'Planck', year: 1858, passed: 1947 },
    { first: 'Katherine', last: 'Blodgett', year: 1898, passed: 1979 },
    { first: 'Ada', last: 'Lovelace', year: 1815, passed: 1852 },
    { first: 'Sarah E.', last: 'Goode', year: 1855, passed: 1905 },
    { first: 'Lise', last: 'Meitner', year: 1878, passed: 1968 },
    { first: 'Hanna', last: 'Hammarström', year: 1829, passed: 1909 }
  ];
```

Comment: `allYearData` is a number, and you're trying to sort a number.

Comment: You're trying to sort by year of death?

Comment: What result are you trying to get? From the code, it seems like you are trying to sort it. But you are using map() function.

Answer (score 3):

The `map` method is not going to be needed for sorting use case you are trying tp make.

```js
let investors =[    { first: 'Albert', last: 'Einstein', year: 1879, passed: 1955 },
                { first: 'Isaac', last: 'Newton', year: 1643, passed: 1727 },
                { first: 'Galileo', last: 'Galilei', year: 1564, passed: 1642 },
                { first: 'Marie', last: 'Curie', year: 1867, passed: 1934 },
                { first: 'Johannes', last: 'Kepler', year: 1571, passed: 1630 },
                { first: 'Nicolaus', last: 'Copernicus', year: 1473, passed: 1543 },
                { first: 'Max', last: 'Planck', year: 1858, passed: 1947 },
                { first: 'Katherine', last: 'Blodgett', year: 1898, passed: 1979 },
                { first: 'Ada', last: 'Lovelace', year: 1815, passed: 1852 },
                { first: 'Sarah E.', last: 'Goode', year: 1855, passed: 1905 },
                { first: 'Lise', last: 'Meitner', year: 1878, passed: 1968 },
                { first: 'Hanna', last: 'Hammarström', year: 1829, passed: 1909 }  
           
 ]
 
 
 const orderedByObjectMapFilter = investors.sort((a, b) => {
 
    return a.passed > b.passed? +1 : -1
 
 });
 
console.log(orderedByObjectMapFilter)
```